# Correct optional route parameters on browsing url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

I am working on Ecommerce project (Asp.Net Mvc3). My routes for product and categories are mentioned below

```
routes.MapLocalizedRoute(
  "Product",
  "p/{productId}/{SeName}",
   new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Product", SeName = UrlParameter.Optional },
);

routes.MapLocalizedRoute(
  "Product", 
  "c/{categoryId}/{SeName}",
  new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Category", SeName = UrlParameter.Optional },
);
```

When use browse url `http://mysite.in/p/123/my-product` it redirects to correct product and same thing happens for category as well.

Now when I provide wrong SeName or Just removes SeName from url it redirects to correct product/category, which is correct. But I want valid SeName to be appended i.e if there is wrong or no SeName in the url sename for repsective product/category should be added in url. Is there any effect on Site SEO of above functinality.

Stackoverflow does the same think i.e though SeName is optional it appends seName if not provided.

Please reply if anybody having worked on same issue.

Comment: This is typically done using an action filter. [This blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/02/21/manipulating-action-method-parameters.aspx/), although not exactly the same issue, should point you in the right direction.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I think this is what i wanted, but would that be feasible to give call to db everytime to check sename in actionfilter and replace if required

Comment: Unless you cache the ID/Name values somewhere, then that would be your only option (I doubt that its more than a few milliseconds)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for ur valuable guidance. You can post ur comment as answer so that i can accept it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke does any of these two methods affects SEO of site, if u have knowledge abt it please share.

Comment: I'm not an expert on SEO but from what I've read, it can be better except you lose any benefit if you later change the name of the product or category, or if a user enters the correct id but a non-matching name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is referred to as a 'slug' and is typically handled in an action filter. Phil Haack has a good article [Manipulating Action Method Parameters](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/02/21/manipulating-action-method-parameters.aspx/) that explains it in detail. The basic concept is to handle the filters `OnActionExecuting` method to extract the route value for the `ID` parameter, then look up the corresponding name from the database and add that value to the `Name` parameter.