# MVC URL automatically changed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, routes

As I know, StackOverflow is based on MVC.NET, and now when I'm using MVC to design a website, I came to this problem.

For example, this url : stackoverflow.com/questions/26704469/sql-query-to-affect-multiple-rows-dynamically

From what I understand in MVC routing rules, this is the part that really makes sense :

- **stackoverflow.com/questions/26704469**, the rest : `sql-query-to-affect-multiple-rows-dynamically` is only for lucid or SEO purposes
- when i enter this part : `stackoverflow.com/questions/26704469`, the address bar will automatically change to the full link  : `stackoverflow.com/questions/26704469/sql-query-to-affect-multiple-rows-dynamically` (this is what I want to achieve)

Now I also want to apply this approach into my project, but I don't know how

My question is how can we achieve this in MVC?

Comment: [This question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648823/correct-optional-route-parameters-on-browsing-url/26650805?s=1|0.8661#26650805) might hep you get started

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, this is very informative