# Redirect to more specific URL via routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

I am using the following routing in my project

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ProductRoute", // Route name
    "product/{id}/{title}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "product", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameters defaults
    new[] { "PriceCompare.Controllers" }
    );
```

The problem at hand is how the url is displayed in return. One can access the URL in any of the following ways:

- http://mywebsite.com/product/22/full-title
- http://mywebsite.com/product/22/half
- http://mywebsite.com/product/22/

All is fine, as all these URLs redirect to the desired place. But, what i think would be nice is even if someone uses the 2nd or 3rd approach, the return URL in browser should show the 1st URI.

Just like StackOverflow. For example if you visit the following URL

**stackoverflow.com/questions/734249/**, your browser address will show the complete URL in browser **stackoverflow.com/questions/734249/asp-net-mvc-url-routing-with-multiple-route-values**

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You should evaluate `title` parameter on your action. If it is empty, you should get the title from database and redirect to the url with the title

Comment: You need to do a 301 redirect when someone comes in on a particular URL, that is how StackOverflow works. How you choose to redirect is probably the question.

Comment: You can do this with an action filter [as per this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648823/correct-optional-route-parameters-on-browsing-url/26650805#26650805)

Answer (score 2):

You can either implement your own `Route` or do something like this in your action:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id, string title = null)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
    {
         var product = // load product
         return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Product",
                                    new { id = id, title = product.Title }));
    }

    // your code
}
```